# In Salesforce trigger why use Trigger.newMap.keySet()?

Tags: trigger

Please explain one thing here - contact Id and account Id, how to identify and why use Trigger.newMap.keySet()?

```
trigger accountTestTrggr on Account (before insert, before update) {
  //This queries all Contacts related to the incoming Account records in a single SOQL query.
  //This is also an example of how to use child relationships in SOQL
  List<Account> accountsWithContacts = [select id, name, (select id, salutation, description, 
                                                                firstname, lastname, email from Contacts) 
                                                                from Account where Id IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet()];
      
  List<Contact> contactsToUpdate = new List<Contact>{};
  // For loop to iterate through all the queried Account records 
  for(Account a: accountsWithContacts){
     // Use the child relationships dot syntax to access the related Contacts
     for(Contact c: a.Contacts){
      System.debug('Contact Id[' + c.Id + '], FirstName[' + c.firstname + '], LastName[' + c.lastname +']');
      c.Description=c.salutation + ' ' + c.firstName + ' ' + c.lastname; 
      contactsToUpdate.add(c);
     }        
   }
      
   //Now outside the FOR Loop, perform a single Update DML statement. 
   update contactsToUpdate;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide more details around what exactly you're trying to achieve/what is the problem?

Comment: Trigger.newMap.keySet() gives you id of the all record which are going to update but in the case of before insert you will get null because record still don't have any id as it is going to insert

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments/answers of others, the ID values for the Account objects are not available in the "before insert" case: those IDs are allocated when the insert is done. But as no child Contact objects can be added until after the Account objects have been inserted the "before insert" case is not necessary and can be removed.

(If the idea of this trigger is to run as part of an upload process of Accounts and Contacts, the Account inserts will always have to done first and unless an artificial Account update is done after the Contacts have also been uploaded the trigger will never have any Contacts to update.)

Your trigger is re-calculating the `Contact.Description` field of the child Contact objects whenever the parent Account is updated. But as that calculation does not use any fields in the Account (that might have changed) that is a strange approach to use; a trigger on Contact would be the more direct and robust approach.

So while querying using the `Trigger.newMap.keySet()` set of IDs and obtaining both the Account (parent) and related Contact (child) objects is generally a good pattern, it isn't a fit to the problem you appear to be trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

A trigger can run on one or more records depending on whether or not a mass update/insert has occurred. In this trigger here, the keyset contains all of the SalesForce Ids of the accounts being updated(but not before insert - after insert would be needed). The query above is requesting all accounts and their children contact records that were just updated since children records cannot be accessed in a trigger without querying for them first.
The contact id, is the SalesForce Id of the children contact records.